# What is a polymorphic association?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I would like to know what a *polymorphic association* is (in data modeling sense), because I understand they are common and I want to learn how to implement them in Rails.

Does the term describe the case where, for example,

- web_post_country

  - a web_post *has (as its subject)* > 0 or 1 countries
  - a country *is described by* 0 or more web_posts
- web_post_country

  - a web_post *has (as its subject)* 0 or 1 regions
  - a region *is described by* 0 or more web_posts
- region_country

  - a region *is in* 1 country
  - a country *has* 0 or more regions

? (These are always a bit tricky to implement).

Once I know ***what*** they are, I will be ready to study the questions and answers here about the second question: ***how*** to ***implement*** them in Rails.

Hope this is not too far out of scope for this forum...my ultimate goal is to learn Rails implementation of polymorphic associations.

Comment: As much as it pains me to say so because you have a clearly written question, yes, this is out of the scope of Stack Overflow. The website is focused on answering questions about specific problems with actual code. If you need to learn the basic mechanics of associations, you're expected to refer to official documentation or other tutorials. You can begin by this one: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html

Comment: Also, **Stack Overflow is not a forum**

Comment: This question may be better handled by another StackExchange site; for example, http://programmers.stackexchange.com/. It is off-topic for StackOverflow.

Comment: Thanks, no problem.  I was afraid it was out of scope.  I did come across the answer just now, so I'm good to go.

Answer (score 1):

**A regular association** is created via primary/foreign keys.

```
User "Bob", id: 1
Book "The Sponge", id: 1, user_id: 1
```

The foreign key `user_id` refers to the primary key of a user.

---

**A polymorphic association** works with primary/foreign keys, plus the "type" of the object:

```
User "Bob", id: 1
Book "The Sponge", id: 1, owner_id: 1, owner_type: "User"
```

Here, we need both fields to retrieve the owner of the book:

> *We know the owner's id is 1, and the owner's type (class) is "User", so let's find the User with  id = 1 !*

---

This means you can have several types of owner: *poly* (several) - *morphic* (type, class)

For example, you could have a Book owned by a Client object:

```
Client "XXX", id: 12
Book "Catalog", id: 2, owner_id: 12, owner_type: "Client" # => owner is client #12
Book "Anoying", id: 3, owner_id: 20, owner_type: "User" # => owner is user #20
```

---

**How to implement polymorphic associations** in Rails framework:

```
class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :owner, polymorphic: true 
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :books, as: :owner
end

class Client < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :books, as: :owner
end
```

Then you can find back the owner of a book with the following lines:

```
book = Book.first
book.owner # => return the owner of the book, can be either Client or User
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example in Rails with easier model names:

```
class Comment
  belongs_to :commentable, polymorphic: true
end

class Article
  has_many :comments, as: :commentable
end

class Photo
  has_many :comments, as: :commentable
end
```

I think the relationships are self explanatory here. More information about polymorphism and Rails [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations).